# Unable to understand why variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am beginner in AngularJS so I'm trying to learn by building POCs. My requirement is simple-

1. User adds details and clicks on "Add Contact" button. This adds the **contact** to an array in controller. (This part is working).
2. This added contact is shown in tabular format, just below the form. (This is also working).
3. In the table where contacts are displayed, I also want to have a delete button which will delete the corresponding contact. (The problem)

Following is the html code-

```
<body ng-app="myApp" class='container'>
    <div ng-controller="Controller1 as ctrl">
        <h1>Contacts Manager</h1>
        <hr>
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Contact Editor</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form role="form" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="contact.firstName"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="contact.lastName"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" maxlength="10" ng-model="contact.phoneNumber"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <input type="checkbox" name="disableAddRec" ng-model="disableAddRec"> <label for="disableAddRec">Disable Adding Contacts</label>
                <span class="pull-right"><button name="addContact" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="disableAddRec" ng-click="ctrl.addToContactList()">Add Contact</button></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" ng-if="ctrl.contactList.length > 0">
               <thead>
                   <tr><th>S. No.</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Phone Number</th><th>Action</th></tr>                       
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   <tr ng-repeat="cntct in ctrl.contactList">
                       <td>{{$index+1}}</td><td>{{cntct.firstName}}</td><td>{{cntct.lastName}}</td><td>{{cntct.phoneNumber}}</td>
                       <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="ctrl.removeContact($index)">Remove</button></td>
                   </tr>
               </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Following is the js code-

```
var myAppRef = angular.module("myApp", []);
myAppRef.controller("Controller1",['$scope', myController1]);
function myController1($scope) {

    this.contactList = [];

    this.addToContactList = function() {
        this.contactList.push($scope.contact);     
        $scope.contact = {};        
    }

    this.removeContact = function(idx) {
        this.contactList.splice(idx,1); // contactList is undefined here... why?
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me identifying, why **contactList** is undefined in **removeContact**?

Comment: These types of error mean `this` isn't what you expect, which means _removeContact_ isn't being invoked on your `myController1` instance, but some other object

Comment: I got this working if I explicitly pass `ctrl.contactList` to _removeContact_ method. But why it doesn't it work without passing, just like _addToContactList_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a wrong context - your inner `this` is not the same as your outer `this`. Either use `$scope` or store a reference to the controller context.

For example:

```
    var self = this;
    self.contactList = [];

    self.addToContactList = function() {
        self.contactList.push($scope.contact);     
        $scope.contact = {};        
    }

    this.removeContact = function(idx) {
        self.contactList.splice(idx,1); // contactList is now defined 
    }
```

Or:

```
    $scope.contactList = [];

    $scope.addToContactList = function() {
        $scope.contactList.push($scope.contact);     
        $scope.contact = {};        
    }

    $scope.removeContact = function(idx) {
        $scope.contactList.splice(idx,1); // contactList is now defined as well
    }
```

Comment: I tried this. Now nothing seems to work. Do I need to change my html as well?

Comment: No, it should work only when you change the controller. Would you mind recreating the issue in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/)?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is the angular version, which one are you using?

Comment: Here on plunker, effects of changing `this`  to `$scope` https://plnkr.co/edit/lIgTZOMijYZc37SiBCIG?p=preview

Comment: I'm using 1.4.4 on my local.

Comment: Hmm, really not sure what's wrong on your local machine, you see the original code works both on plunker and as a snippet here.

Comment: That plunker you sent is not working because it combines "controller as..." syntax with $scope. It works when I removed the controller as syntax: https://plnkr.co/edit/N1Hs0tnweSUL3Rh610SU?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Made slight modifications in your code. I made it working without using "Controller As"

```
<div ng-controller="Controller1">
  <h1>Contacts Manager</h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Contact Editor</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="contact.firstName" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="contact.lastName" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
          <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" maxlength="10" ng-model="contact.phoneNumber" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <input type="checkbox" name="disableAddRec" ng-model="disableAddRec">
      <label for="disableAddRec">Disable Adding Contacts</label>
      <span class="pull-right"><button name="addContact" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="disableAddRec" ng-click="addToContactList()">Add Contact</button></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" ng-if="contactList.length > 0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>S. No.</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="cntct in contactList">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{cntct.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{cntct.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{cntct.phoneNumber}}</td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeContact($index)">Remove</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
var myAppRef = angular.module("myApp", []);
myAppRef.controller("Controller1", ['$scope', myController1]);

function myController1($scope) {

  $scope.contactList = [];

  $scope.addToContactList = function() {
    $scope.contactList.push($scope.contact);
    $scope.contact = {};
  }

  $scope.removeContact = function(idx) {
    $scope.contactList.splice(idx, 1); // contactList is undefined here... why?
  }
}
```

Please check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/Ashyboy/vv8jt6sh/

Answer (score 0):

Your exact code is working here!! Try running it here.

```js
var myAppRef = angular.module("myApp", []);
myAppRef.controller("Controller1",['$scope', myController1]);
function myController1($scope) {

    this.contactList = [];

    this.addToContactList = function() {
        this.contactList.push($scope.contact);     
        $scope.contact = {};        
    }

    this.removeContact = function(idx) {
        this.contactList.splice(idx,1); // contactList is undefined here... why?
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" class='container'>
    <div ng-controller="Controller1 as ctrl">
        <h1>Contacts Manager</h1>
        <hr>
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Contact Editor</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form role="form" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="contact.firstName"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="contact.lastName"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" maxlength="10" ng-model="contact.phoneNumber"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <input type="checkbox" name="disableAddRec" ng-model="disableAddRec"> <label for="disableAddRec">Disable Adding Contacts</label>
                <span class="pull-right"><button name="addContact" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="disableAddRec" ng-click="ctrl.addToContactList()">Add Contact</button></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" ng-if="ctrl.contactList.length > 0">
               <thead>
                   <tr><th>S. No.</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Phone Number</th><th>Action</th></tr>                       
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   <tr ng-repeat="cntct in ctrl.contactList">
                       <td>{{$index+1}}</td><td>{{cntct.firstName}}</td><td>{{cntct.lastName}}</td><td>{{cntct.phoneNumber}}</td>
                       <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="ctrl.removeContact($index)">Remove</button></td>
                   </tr>
               </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I even tried to run it on my local. It works. It should in yours too. Is this the only code in your file? Rest of the code might be causing the issue or some syntax error. Dont know just a guess. Try creating a new file and just add these code snippets and see if it runs in your machine.